# 「手があれてひっかかっちゃう」とは何ですか？

Tags: meaning, translation, interpretation

日本の小説を外国語に翻訳している外国人です。

今、手がけている小説にこんな文章があります。
（Aは主人公、Bは別の登場人物）

---

> Bさんは布を包もうとして、Aをちらっと見ました。
>
> 「これはわたしの自慢のべールなのよ。あなた、ちょっと見たくない？」
>
> 「ええ、とても」
>
> Aはこたえました。
>
> Bさんは「**手があれてひっかかっちゃうから・・・**」とつぶやきながら、手のひらを合わせて何回もこすると、レースのはじを持ってひろげました。
>
> 「まあ、きれい！」
>
> Aは思わずさけびました。
>
> 細い細い糸で、一面に花や、鳥の模様が編みこまれています。Aは天使の羽があるとしたら、こんなものかしらと思いました。

---

「手があれてひっかかっちゃう」の意味はちょっと自信ないのですが、「今、私の手が荒くて、皮膚がカサカサ（皮膚が剥がれて小さな皮が固く立っている状態？）なので、こんな手で繊細なベールに触るとベールのレースに傷つけてしまうかもしれない。まず手をこすって、手の平の立っている小さな皮を寝かせよう」という意味じゃないかと想像していますが、合っているでしょうか。

Comment: Sounds like a flawless analysis and perfect explanation to me. But on the other hand (pun intended) wouldn't the application of friction between hands only worsen the situation by further vaporizing what's left of the already scarce moisture which could protect the cloth from rough skin? Maybe **ペ**ール should be **ベ**ール? And would one really さけぶ in such situation? 声をあげました would make sense though, unless there was an insect or something.

Comment: ごめんなさい。「まあ、きれい！」とさけびました、でした。飛ばしてしまってすみません。編集しておきました。

確かにそうですね！こすると手がより悪化しそうですね・・・。考えてもみませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

> 今、私の手が荒くて、皮膚がカサカサ（皮膚が剥がれて小さな皮が固く立っている状態？）なので、こんな手で繊細なベールに触るとベールのレースに傷つけてしまうかもしれない。まず手をこすって、手の平の立っている小さな皮を寝かせよう

良いと思います！　(^^)

ひとつだけ気になったのは、「手が[荒]{あら}くて」「手が[荒]{あら}い」ではなく、「手が[荒]{あ}れていて」「手が[荒]{あ}れる」です。（ちなみに、「手荒れ」という名詞もあります。）「手が荒れる」とは、水仕事や寒さのせいで、手の皮膚がカサカサになったり皮がむけたりすることです。

Comment: 私は、パンストを履くときに、手が荒れていて引っかかってしまって、パンストに電線が入ったことがあります。( ;∀;)

Comment: 「手が荒い」じゃなくて「手が荒れる」ですね！勉強になりました！ありがとうございます。

Comment: I think what's happening to the pantyhose is **伝**線.

Comment: ^ @dungarian おおっ　ほんまや！